# fuelphp find(first) doesn't work

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'm just trying to get data by find('first'),but it doesn't work.

This is code in controller.

```
 $result = Model_questionstate::find('first');
```

This is model.

```
    class Model_questionstate extends Model_Crud{
        protected static $_table_name = 'questionstate';
        protected static $_primary_key = 'id';
    }
```

This shows

**Fatal Error! ErrorException 
[ Fatal Error ]: Unsupported operand types
COREPATH/classes/model/crud.php @ line 210**

This doesn't show any error.

```
   $result = Model_questionstate::find();
```

What is wrong with my codes?

Comment: What does the `first` mean? The first data?

Comment: Yes, I've heard find(first) enables me to get first data. find(last) is last,find(all) is all data.Is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [`Model_questionstate::find_one_by()`](http://fuelphp.com/dev-docs/classes/model_crud/methods.html#/method_find_one_by).
It works by specifying a condition, and returns one record. I'm sure this fits your needs, since returning one row without any filtering is not a very common task.

By the way, Fuel doesn't support `find('first')` in the Model_Crud (however it does in the Orm). Take a look at [`Model_Crud`'s source](https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.8/develop/classes/model/crud.php#L192) if you're interested the insides.

Comment: Thanks! it worked and fits my needs.However,the fact that there isn't find('first') is a bit mysterious. in this document [link](http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/crud.html), there seems to be find('first')...

Comment: Yes, that's what I referred to as the Orm. Those are different Models, and they DO support `find('first')`. I recommend you to check out the Orm, and how that works, I found it a much more usable approach to Models.

Comment: `find('first')` would work if your model extended `\Orm\Model` instead of `Model_Crud`.

Comment: Thanks! I understand I must use  Orm.i'll  check it.

Comment: You don't have to, but it makes your life easier, if you learn it :)